# Set identity off in azure sql table

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a table which includes an identity column but i cant remove the identity property.

Is there a way to disable it? Or a way to make a copy of the entire table without identity property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that you may not be able to drop the column if it referenced by a clustered index, and you can't drop all clustered indexes for a table because SqlAzure tables must always have a clustered index.

This means that you may have to jump through the following hoops (for at least your last clustered index, which may well be your primary key):

- rename your clustered index
- create a temp version of the table (with a new clustered index)
- copy the data from the current table
- drop the current table
- rename the temp table to the current name

This roughly looks like this:

```
-- Rename clustered index
EXECUTE sp_rename N'PK_My_Current_PK', N'PK_My_Current_PK_OLD',  'OBJECT'

-- If you have any FK constraints on the table, then drop them
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable DROP CONSTRAINT FK_My_Foreign_Key

-- Create the new version of your table - because this is SQLAzure it must have a clustered index
CREATE TABLE dbo.tmp_MyTable (
    MyID int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_My_Current_PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (MyID)
)

-- Copy the data into the temp table from the old table
INSERT INTO dbo.tmp_MyTable (MyID)
    SELECT MyID FROM dbo.MyTable 

-- Drop the old table 
DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable 

-- Rename the new table
EXECUTE sp_rename N'tmp_MyTable', N'MyTable', 'OBJECT' 

-- Recreate any foreign key constraints
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable WITH CHECK ADD FK_My_Foreign_Key FOREIGN KEY (MyID)
    REFERENCES dbo.MyForeignTable (MyID)
```

Hope that helps

A

**Edit:** As @PhilBolduc pointed out SqlAzure tables require a clustered index, not a primary key. I've amended the terminology above accordingly - the principle of the answer still remains.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly my problem. Too bad it cant be done easier thought. Thank you very much

Comment: The PK constraint in SqlAzure is a very frustrating limitation (or difference - I guess that's a more appropriate word) that other versions do not have.  Glad the answer pinpointed it.

Comment: Tables in SQL Azure do NOT require a PK.  They DO require a clustered index.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx#cir

Comment: @PhilBolduc - yes, you're right, thanks.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can not remove an Identity column without dropping it unfortunately. Alternetivly add a new column with a temp name, update the new column value and then drop the previous column.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename ADD newcolumnname INT

UPDATE dbo.tablename SET newcolumnname = oldcolumnname FROM dbo.tablename

ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename DROP COLUMN oldcolumnname
```

that should do it. unless i have misunderstood your questions?

Comment: Sorry. I should have mentioned that i had the problem mentioned by alergy that i couldn't delete it because of the primary key on the column. But thanks!